# Anything different vs Any difference

Tags: differences

Is there a difference in meaning between the following two phrases.

> I'm not noticing anything different.

and

> I'm not noticing any difference.

I have a feeling that the former is a bit more localised as it suggests something to do with 'thing' ..

Comment: You're right, *anything* does feel more localized to me. *I'm not noticing any difference* also seems slightly more formal by comparison.

Comment: What do you guys mean by "localized"? Having a more restricted use, i.e. usable in fewer contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small *difference yes*

When asking for anything different you are asking for a particular thing that changed.

When asking for any difference then you can refer to something that changed but not particularly to a specific thing.

*any difference between the two* you are asking in general for the difference

*anything different between the two*  you are asking between a particular thing(s) being different.

E.g.

is there any difference between these two apples (this will make you look for the differences between the two apples)

Is there anything different between this apple and this apple (this makes you look for particular differences)

Answer (score 1):

No, they mean the same thing.

I wouldn't usually say the first one though, so I'm not sure if it's right or wrong. Perhaps "I haven't noticed anything different."

I'm native English.